# load showing image in listview with custom baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a android project and i am implementing an adapter for my listview.

My adapter simply load an image and a text together and show them on the listview
but it's not efficient to load all image on cach.

So i'm looking for a way just to load image which are shown to the user on listview and every time the user scroll up/down the images of list being update

Is there any way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In List View, getView() method of the BaseAdapter is called for only those views which are shown currently on screen. So you can use Nostra Universal Image Loader library to load the images asynchronously.